# How to remove complete header and footer from checkout/cart and afterwards all pages in magento

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

I have to remove complete header and footer from checkout/cart page to all onwards pages in magento 1.7. All I know that I need to add `<remove name="header"/>` in the "checkout.xml" file but whenever I'm trying to add that same line, Either nothing reflecting on front-end or a blank page appear on front-end.

Answer (score 1):

In your local.xml use below code

To remove header and footer from **Cart** Page:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
  <remove name="header"/>
  <remove name="footer"/>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

To remove header and footer from **Checkout Onepage**:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
   <remove name="header"/>
   <remove name="footer"/>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Comment: u r talking about app/etc/local.xml file ? so where exactly should I place this code ?

Comment: Inside your design layout folder
For eg: app\design\frontend\default(YourProjectNameSpace)\default\layout\local.xml
But if you are not using local.xml you can paste  the above code in your page.xml

Comment: no after adding these lines of code in page.xml, on frontend only a blank white page is appearing

Comment: where did you add it exactly ?

Comment: i tried to add it in default section, at the beginning

Comment: Add it in the end before </layout> so that you can know what changes you have done in your layout structure.

Comment: no its not working..I added it as u said..but I'm getting a blank white page on frontend

Comment: What is your file location ?

Comment: in my theme local.xml is not available in theme's layout directory. So I added these code in default/My_theme/layout/page.xml. I place the code just before closing of </layout>

Comment: Try the below location
`app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\page.xml`

Comment: my theme has its own page.xml file and i think it will always overwrite default/default/page.xml file.. U want me to remove page.xml file from my current theme

Answer (score 1):

In ur custom theme layout folder inside layout folder in ur  local.xml copy this code for removing header and footer from checkout/cart page

`<checkout_cart_index>
     <remove name="header"/>
     <remove name="footer"/>
 </checkout_cart_index>`

For removing checkout/onepage

`<checkout_onepage_index>
    <remove name="header"/>
    <remove name="footer"/>
 </checkout_onepage_index>`

one thing remember copy this code after closing default tag in ur local.xml if u insert this code in default tag it will remove header nd footer from all pages

Answer (score 0):

```
    <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
                   <reference name="root">
                        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/empty.phtml</template></action>
            </reference>
   </checkout_cart_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may follow this steps:

step 1:

Go to app/design/frontend/yourtheme/layout/checkout.xml
add these two lines after this lines(

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <label>Shopping Cart</label>
```

)

```
<remove name="header"/>
<remove name="footer"/>
```

step 2:
If you are using any extension for checkout then 
go to app/design/frontend/yourtheme/layout/your_extension_checkout.xml

add these two lines after this lines(

```
<onepagecheckout_index_index translate="label">
<label>One Page Checkout</label>
```

)

```
<remove name="header"/>
<remove name="footer"/>
```

otherwise go to your theme/layout/checkout.xml(same step1 file) and

add above two lines after this lines(`<checkout_onepage_index translate="label"> <label>One Page Checkout</label>`)

step 3: clearing your magento cache

Comment: onepagecheckout.xml is not available in my magento directory

Comment: onepagecheckout.xml file is  available for me because I have enabled onepage checkout extension.

Comment: Are you using default magento checkout?

Comment: Ok.. Have you find "<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">" in your theme/layout/checkout.xml file

Comment: If you find, add following lines  <remove name="header"/>
<remove name="footer"/>  after <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout</label>

Comment: yes I have found  "<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">" in my theme/layout/checkout.xml file and also I added the code just below <lable> tag. but its generating a blank white page on front end

Comment: I think you are make any syntax error in your xml file

Comment: one more thing u should be aware about. If m adding <remove name="footer"/> before closing of </checkout_cart_index> then its working fine and footer is not appearing on cart page. But when I try to add <remove name="header"/> its giving me an empty blank white page only

Comment: I gues there should be a proper position for adding <remove name="header"/>

Comment: Inside your  <checkout_onepage_index translate="label"> tag, have you find <remove name="left"/> ??

Comment: yes there is <remove name="left"/> and <remove name="right"/> both. and both are place together just below <label> tag

Comment: add remove tag for header and footer below this remove left and right tag

Comment: then its not working..then only a blank n white page is appearing on frontend

Comment: Is blank page appears on both cart and checkout page?

Comment: no..for those only I'm adding the code.. If I'm adding this for cart page then cart page gets blank and if I'm adding it for onepage then onepage turned to blank

Comment: But this is work for me after uninstall my onepage checkout extension.

Comment: removal of left,right and footer is working fine..only removal of header is not working. n As soon as i place this code anywhere frontend turned to blank.

Comment: ok can you check the reference name of header in your page.xml?

Comment: <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">

Answer (score 0):

You need to write in your XML file:

```
<remove name="header" />
<remove name="footer" />
```

Answer (score -1):

please goto page.xml for you template folder

```
 <default translate="label" module="page">
<remove name="header"/>
<remove name="footer"/>

</default>
```

For  only checkout Please goto  checkout.xml

```
    <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
 <remove name="header"/>
    <remove name="footer"/>
</checkout_cart_index>
<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
 <remove name="header"/>
    <remove name="footer"/>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Comment: It removed header and footer on all pages.. I need to remove only on cart and onepage